# Using Raspberry Pi 2 B with Pan Tilt and OpenCV 3.0.0 for the 1st Time

Tags: python, pi-2, camera, opencv

I am very new to Raspberry Pi, and This is my first time using it. I have read a lot from the documentation on the [official website](http://raspberrypi.org), and I really got great things. After that I installed OpenCV 3 with Non-free Modules from [pyimagesearch](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/10/26/how-to-install-opencv-3-on-raspbian-jessie/), and I really recommend anyone new reading this post, and want to install OpenCV to follow up with these amazing well organized steps.

What I want to ask about is how to make my code I made on Python on my PC run on RasPi, can codes be run in parallel, or do I have to put everything in a single .py file and run it ??. Are there any references that I can read from, or anyone can help me ?

Another question, I am not using the Raspberry Pi camera module, just a standard webcam, do I have to write something in the code, like import picamera, or I just write cv2.VideoCapture() and put the number of the port that the camera is connected to between the parenthesis ??

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Note: the RasPi is running on Jessie, installed via NOOBS as recommended by the official website

Comment: Hi Osama, wellcome to RPi board. Do you want write your Python code on your PC and upload to RPi or directly change code in the RPi, i didn't get sorry

Comment: @ahmetertem I have the code already running on my PC, and it's working well, but with the built-in camera in the PC, However, I am using another camera on the RasPi.                                                                                             I can get the code on RasPi from my GitHub page, it's not a big deal